# How can I add a bar showing the total of my values in my bar chart report?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2012

How can I add a bar showing the total of the values of a column in my bar chart report? 
I can add the total in the table report and it shows in the table preview, but it isn't reflected in the chart!

Comment: I think you will need to add a lot more detail to your question before you will be able to get a helpful answer.  Try including what you have tried so far, what that result looks like, and how you would like it to look instead.

Comment: Have you considered REPLICATE to create an asterisk for each 1000 or something like that?

Comment: @APH : Here below you can find my bar chart. I would like to include a last bar at the end of the bars which shows the total of all the other bars, one in blue and one in purple. Can I do such a thing in Visual studio? Thanks.


![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rRAv0.png

Comment: I think there's no other way to show the total than changing the underlying query..